# Desktop startup takes long time occasionally

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, startup

It takes long time to get Xfce desktop after giving login credentials in Xubuntu 20.04 occasionally. Normally it takes only few seconds, but sometimes it takes maybe half minute or so. During that time LightDM screen is shown, and there seems to be a lot of mass storage activity. Why does it take long time sometimes?

Clip from `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` shows the delay:

```
[+9.41s] DEBUG: User jarnos authorized
[+9.43s] DEBUG: Greeter sets language en_US
[+9.47s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session xubuntu
[+41.78s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
```

Comment: With that amount of information really nobody can give any qualified answer. If you add more information to your question, your chances might greatly increase.

Comment: @HuHa sure, but can you be more specific?

Comment: It's YOU who needs to be more specific. What is "a long time"? What do you see happening, or what do you expect to see and don't? Did you try to log in from another machine with `ssh` and monitor with `top` what's going on? Did you check any logs? (Xorg.log, .xsession-errors)? How often does it happen? When? What do you have in your desktop's autostart folder? I mean, with a reputation of 4119 you should have a rough idea how to ask and how to do things around a Linux system.

Comment: @Huha Are you mad at me? I am not an expert in debugging logging in. My Ask Ubuntu reputation is based on other things. I have not used ssh to inspect the problem, yet. It is a bit troublesome, as the problem is not always or regularly reproducible. Besides, I have been busy. I tried checking output of some `journalctl` command sometime, but could not figure out the cause. I will try to check some logs next time it happens.